# Spring with Hibernate: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

I have developed a REST- API with Spring Web and Hibernate. 
I deployed it in two server instances and it runs without any problem for about 5 months. Now it is mostly working but in some periods "**MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**" with message "**Duplicate entry '235648' for key 'PRIMARY'**" are thrown (te duplicate id is changing in the exceptions).

The class, for which the exception is thrown, looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Metadata", catalog = "data")
public class Metadata{
    private Long id;
    private String field1;  
    private String field2;
    //...           

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    //More Getters and Setters...
}
```

There was neither change to java code nor changes on the MySql-database.
Do you have any idea why it stopped working properly?

Comment: Did you manually enter some rows in database?

Comment: Was the generation table created by hibernate? or there was an already existing on in the database?

Comment: Set `GenerationType.AUTO`

Comment: @KedarJoshi: No. I have not entered any row.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski: Yes, table was created by hibernate and worked for months.

Comment: are both application server share same database?

Comment: @lucid: Yes, they do.

Comment: @AlexandarG: according to [this blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/)  it would use same strategy (Hibernate 5 and MySQL). Do you think GenerationType.IDENTITY could solve the problem?

Comment: @user1986745: `AUTO` has done good job for me so far,  but keep in mind that I'm using OracleDB, not MySQL. Anyways I think is worth trying ;)

Comment: "AUTO" is not a strategy as such. It simply leaves it for the JPA provider to do as it feels. "IDENTITY" means use MySQL "AUTO_INCREMENT". Any basic JPA docs would tell you that

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the number of requests which end up creating entities which use that table for id generation has increased.

One of the remedies would be to catch that exception in a parent method and retry (probably this would be some kind of `PessimisticLock` exception as the id table has to be physically locked while retrieving and updating its content).

Another one would be to increase the `allocationSize` option, which for you is 50 being the default if no custom set-up is done. You would need to reenter the hibernate default table / columns names as this has been already created in the database:

```
@Id
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
@TableGenerator(
        name="tableGen", 
        table="hibernate_sequences", 
        pkColumnName="sequence_name", 
        valueColumnName="next_val", 
        pkColumnValue="default",
        allocationSize=100 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="tableGen")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Here is a nice post which explains the scalability pitfalls of a TABLE generation strategy -> [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Well, the post explains, that the application will slow down. Of course, that is not good, but duplicate primary keys sounds for me like an other problem. What exactly does 'allocationSize' do?

Comment: When the number of request to that id table increases, such exceptions occur.. meaning when one request locks the table for its own needs, another tries to do the same, but it cannot due to the lock, hence the exception. If you increase the allocation size, you decrease the number of roundtrips to that table and theoretically decrease the chance of that exception

Comment: That explanation still makes no sense. If the request can't lock the sequence-table then some kind of a CannotLockException is expected. A duplicate entry for a primary key means that there is already an ID that has been generated by the sequence. But this ID is - somehow - already in use.

Answer (score 1):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

worked for me.